# Which version of JavaScript (ECMAScript) does JS++ extend?

Tags: js++

Since JS++ is a superset that extends the JavaScript language, which specific specification of JavaScript does JS++ extend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS++ extends the ECMAScript 3 specification (ECMAScript 3rd Edition, Dec 1999). This should provide browser compatibility for Internet Explorer 6+, Firefox 1.0+, Chrome, Safari, and Opera.

There are [some changes](https://docs.onux.com/en-US/Developers/JavaScript-PP/Language-Guide/compatibility-javascript), such as semicolons being required.

---

Sources:

- https://docs.onux.com/en-US/Developers/JavaScript-PP/Language-Guide/compatibility-javascript
- https://johnresig.com/blog/versions-of-javascript/

Comment: Note, I think ES3.1 adds strict mode. Is that effective on JS++? More info: http://jaoo.dk/dl/jaoo-aarhus-2008/slides//PratapLakshman_ECMAScript31.pdf (I guess it's about ES3.1). I'm asking this because it'll affect run time errors if someone expresses `'strict mode'` or `'use strict'`.

Comment: There is no ECMAScript "strict mode" in JS++. JS++ does not extend ECMAScript 3.1. It is a superset of the specification published in December 1999: https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf

Comment: So I recommend stripping "strict mode" and "use strict" as expression statements.